# spork-minitest error but tests pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spork, minitest

I finally created a Windows environment for new Rails applications that I like. Everything was working until I decided to create a how-to for it. You can find the steps on this [blog post](http://www.manueldeleon.com/Blog/post/2012/07/30/Rails-Testing-on-Windows-%28The-Fast-and-Easy-Way%29.aspx).

I did a fresh install to make sure everything was on the up and up. After everything is said and done the tests run fine and I do get a growl popup but the autotest window shows the following error. What's going on?

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-minitest-0.0.3/bin/testdrb:7:in `exit': can't convert DRb::DRbObject into Integer (TypeError)
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-minitest-0.0.3/bin/testdrb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin/testdrb:19:in `load'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin/testdrb:19:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to install the gem spork-testunit